# How I can find if the first node does not have a parent element in XSLT?

Tags: xpath, xls

I am new to XSLT and I have a XML like:

```
<ROWSET>
  <ROW>
    <a set of elements>, may or may not have parentnode element
  </ROW>
  <ROW>
    <a set of elements>, have parentnode element
  </ROW>
  <ROW>
    <a set of elements>, have parentnode element
  </ROW>
</ROWSET>
```

I want to check if the first row has a parentnode element? The rest of ROWs must have the parentnode element. I use:

```
<xsl:if test="not (/ROWSET/ROW/PARENTNODE)">
   Do something
</xsl:if>
```

As the rest of the ROWs must have the parentnode in them, so the test always return false. Therefore, I use a variable

```
<xsl:variable name="firstRow" select = "/ROWSET/ROW"/> 
<xsl:if test="not ($firstRow/PARENTNODE)">
   Do something
</xsl:if>
```

Unfornately, it always returns false as well. How can I achieve my goal to find out if the first row has parentnode or not?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: `not(/ROWSET/ROW[1]/PARENTNODE)`

Comment: but there is no `PARENTNODE` nor a `parentnode` (note that case **does** make a difference) in your sample xml at all?

Answer (score 0):

I got it. Just use the position of the ROW:

```
<xsl:variable name="firstRow" select = "/ROWSET/ROW[1]"/>
```